# vSphere ESXi - Use both HP ProLiant DL360 G7 and DL360p Gen8 in the same cluster

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, vmware-vsphere, hp-proliant

I have vSphere cluster with few HP DL360 G7 servers, with Intel X5675 processor.

I want to buy new server, HP 360 Gen8 with E5-2600 processors.

Can I have this 2 kinds of servers in the same cluster, and have vMotion without using EVC (currently I don't use EVC)? I know that in order to use vMotion the processors should be compatible, and I know the 2 servers are from different series, but does it affect my ability to use vMotion? Are the instruction sets are enough compatible?

Will I be able to use vMotion? Is this processor compatible?

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I've done this with G7 and Gen8 HP ProLiant servers running on X5660 and E5-2690 CPUs.

This works just fine, as long as you enable [VMware Enhanced vMotion Compatibility (EVC)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003212) at the cluster level. At this point, you should enable EVC while all of your machines are still the same processor generation. Set it to the ***Intel® Westmere* (L3)** level.

When you add your new Gen8 system(s) to the cluster, its processor capabilities will be downgraded to the Westmere CPU's mask (instruction sets). That's what will allow vmotion between the systems.

Before you do this, please upgrade the firmware of your Gen8 system. [**There's a bug with this specific setup**](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2046072) that requires a BIOS update.

If I were you, I would get another G7 server if you just need capacity. It's only one generation behind and would be far less expensive in this case.

If I were building a new cluster today, it would be on the Gen8 platform. But I tend not to want dissimilar servers in the same cluster for long periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003212) you can use multiple processor architectures with EVC.

However, because the Xeon E5 series uses the Ivy Bridge architecture, you will need to use vCenter Server 5.1 - see the final table.

Also, you may not be able to use the whole feature-set of the E5-2600 if you use EVC. The X5675 is based on the Westmere architecture, which means that the EVC base-line will be set at that level.